# Ruby Koan: Constants become symbols

Tags: ruby, symbols

In the about_symbols.rb Ruby Koan (https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans), I have the following code:

```
    RubyConstant = "What is the sound of one hand clapping?"
    def test_constants_become_symbols
      all_symbols = Symbol.all_symbols

      assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(:"nonexistent")

      assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(:"What is the sound of one hand clapping?")
      assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?("What is the sound of one hand clapping?".to_sym)
    end
```

As is, the test passes.

Three questions:

1. Why does the first assert pass? `:"nonexistent"` should not be included in all_symbols but it is included so I must be misunderstanding something.
2. When I comment out the second assert, the test fails because `"What is the sound of one hand clapping?".to_sym` is not included in all_symbols whereas `:"What is the sound of one hand clapping?"` is included. Since they are equivalent, why does the last assert fail? Also, why does it pass when the second assert is not commented out? (Why does the second assert have any effect on the third assert?)
3. To my knowledge, the point of this Ruby Koan was to demonstrate that constants become symbols (at least, that's what I'm inferring from the method name). Since RubyConstant is a constant with the value `"What is the sound of one hand clapping?"`, why isn't `"What is the sound of one hand clapping?".to_sym` included in the list of symbols? The only explanation that I can think of is that, contrary to the method name, constants do not in fact become symbols.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Same question asked here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295776/ruby-koans-75-test-constants-become-symbols-correct-answer?lq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

hoha has it right but I'll try to expand and clarify a bit.

The interpreter will create the `:nonexistent` symbol when it parses `test_constants_become_symbols`. Then, when you run it, `Symbol.all_symbols` is called to get a list of all known symbols and `:nonexistent` is in the list. Also note that the double quotes on `"nonexistent"` are a syntax issue rather than an internal representation issue so `:nonexistent` and `:"nonexistent"` are the same thing.

If you comment out this one:

```
  assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(:"What is the sound of one hand clapping?")
```

then the `:"What is the sound of one hand clapping?"` symbol will not be seen by the parser and so it won't be in the `all_symbols` array. The `.to_sym` method call on the following line is executed when `test_constants_become_symbols` is executed; so, the `:"What is the sound of one hand clapping?"` symbol is created after you get your `all_symbols` and this will fail:

```
  assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?("What is the sound of one hand clapping?".to_sym)
```

If you execute `test_constants_become_symbols` again in the same interpreter instance (with the second `assert_equal` still commented out) then both uncommented `assert_equal` calls will pass as the first run through `test_constants_become_symbols` will create the `:"What is the sound of one hand clapping?"` and the second `Symbol.all_symbols` will include it in the returned array.

Running your code in `irb` without wrapping it in a `def` might help you see what's going on.

Comment: To my knowledge, the point of this Ruby Koan was to demonstrate that constants become symbols (at least, that's what I'm inferring from the method name). Since RubyConstant is declared, why isn't `"What is the sound of one hand clapping?".to_sym` included in the list of symbols? The only explanation that I can think of is that, contrary to the method name, constants do not in fact become symbols. Any thoughts?

Comment: It isn't the value of the constant that becomes a symbol. It is the name of the constant. So `Symbol.all_symbols.include? :RubyConstant` would be true.

Comment: The _name_ of the constant becomes a symbol, but not the _value_ of the constant. Try this: `Zoo="Zee"; p Symbol.all_symbols.grep(/^Z/) #=> [:ZeroDivisionError, :Zoo]`

Comment: @HarrySteinhilber's comment is the answer

Comment: @HarrySteinhilber If you use `:RubyConstant` would that not just be parsed when parsing def and thus create the symbol even if it did not exist?

When I try code liek the following:

`assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(RubyConstant.to_sym)` the assertion fails, although from the above comments, it looks like it should pass.

Comment: @ZenBalance: I think it depends on when `Symbol.all_symbols` and `RubyConstant.to_sym` are evaluated. If `to_sym` comes first then `all_symbols` will include it, otherwise it might not be there.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a Ruby guru but it looks like interpreter created this symbols during `def` expression evaluation. That's why these symbols are already there when you call `Symbol.all_symbols`. Third `assert` fails with second one being commented out because `"string".to_sym` creates symbol during methods execution i.e. after you got available symbols with `all_symbols = Symbol.all_symbols`.