# What to learn from Ruby Koan nº 75?

Tags: ruby

Koan code, number 75:

```
      in_ruby_version("mri") do
        RubyConstant = "What is the sound of one hand clapping?"
        def test_constants_become_symbols
          all_symbols = Symbol.all_symbols

          assert_equal __, all_symbols.include?(__)
        end
      end
```

I'm a bit confused with it because I've just found that any symbol tested against the "all_symbols.include?(__)" will match "true". For example, all of the following should work:

```
    assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(:RubyConstant)
    assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(:"What is the sound of one hand clapping?")
    assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(:AnythingElseYouCouldWriteHere)
```

What is it to learn with "constants_become_symbols" at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ruby, variables that start with capital letters become [constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(programming)). The goal of the koan is to teach you that constants become symbols in ruby and get added to the ruby's symbols table.

```ruby
in_ruby_version("mri") do
  RubyConstant = "What is the sound of one hand clapping?"
  def test_constants_become_symbols
    all_symbols = Symbol.all_symbols

    assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?("RubyConstant".to_sym)
  end
end
```

Also notice how it says `"RubyConstant".to_sym` instead of `:RubyConstant`. It's to avoid confusion since the ruby interpreter will automatically create a symbol when it parses a ruby function, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5358888/1725658).

Comment: Meanwhile, [this is the sound of one hand clapping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1tsCOkCoC8)

Comment: Whoa, thank you! These constants are scope limited, right? Or its kind of a global stuff?

Comment: Since `RubyConstant` is defined in `AboutSymbols` class, it's bound to that scope and you have to access it via scope operator at global level with `::AboutSymbols::RubyConstant`. Read more about ruby constants [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html). Also, take a look at the koans in AboutConstants.