# Ruby Koans #75 test_constants_become_symbols, correct answer?

Tags: ruby, symbols

My question builds upon this question: [Ruby Koan: Constants become symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358727/ruby-koan-constants-become-symbols). I have the following code:

```
in_ruby_version("mri") do
  RubyConstant = "What is the sound of one hand clapping?"
  def test_constants_become_symbols
    all_symbols = Symbol.all_symbols

    assert_equal __, all_symbols.include?(__)
  end
end
```

Is the correct answer supposed to be the following?

```
    assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?("RubyConstant".to_sym)
```

I know I shouldn't just do this:

```
    assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(:RubyConstant)
```

because then I could put anything in there and it would still be true

```
    assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(:DoesNotMatter)
```

Apologies in advance for asking simple a "yes or no" question. I was curious as to know what the "right" answer is. I would have preferred to just ask this question in the comments in the previous post I mentioned above but I couldn't without making a separate post.

Comment: So long as you rely on include? to only return `true` or `false`, instead of `assert_equal`, you could just use `assert Symbol.all_symbols.include( "RubyConstant" )`.

Comment: I think for this exercise, I am being asked to fill in the blanks. But yes, `assert Symbol.all_symbols.include("RubyConstant")` should also return `true`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*NOTE: the following answer only applies to environments like irb, where Ruby code is being executed line by line. When executing code in a file, Ruby scans the entire file for symbols before executing anything, so the following details are not accurate. I've not deleted this answer because it exposes an interesting edge case, but see [@GlichMr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13295929/289274)'s answer for a better explanation of the problem.*

You can safely do the following, because `Symbol.all_symbols` returns a copy of the array of symbols, not a reference.

```
assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(:RubyConstant)
```

I think that is the intended answer to the koan, and it's why `all_symbols` is defined rather than calling `Symbol.all_symbols` directly. For some evidence, see the following:

```
>> X = 1
=> 1
>> all_symbols = Symbol.all_symbols; nil
=> nil
>> Y = 2
=> 2
>> all_symbols.include?(:X)
=> true
>> all_symbols.include?(:Y)
=> false
```

Using `String#to_sym` would make it possible to make these calls against `Symbol.all_symbols` directly, but is not necessary for solving this koan.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds right. Do you know why `assert_equal true, all_symbols.include?(:WhateverConstant)` is still passing for me?

Comment: Hmm.. I guess this is more complicated than I had anticipated. If executing code line by line, such as in IRB, what I said is correct. But if executing a file, Ruby scans the entire file for Symbols before it actually executes anything, which means that the symbols are included in Symbol.all_symbols even if they are defined *after* the line where you assign `all_symbols = Symbol.all_symbols`. I'll put a note on my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 13):

Here's what I got:

```
in_ruby_version("mri") do
  RubyConstant = "What is the sound of one hand clapping?"
  def test_constants_become_symbols
    all_symbols_as_strings = Symbol.all_symbols.map { |x| x.to_s }

    assert_equal true, all_symbols_as_strings.include?("RubyConstant")
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the answer the Koan is looking for as RubyConstant will be a `Symbol` that will be created for the duration of the program's execution.

Answer (score 5):

`Symbol.all_symbols` contains every symbol that was referenced - variable names, class names, constant names, actual symbols. What actually this variable contains is implementation defined, but in Ruby MRI, many symbols are already on this list.

```
irb(main):001:0> Constant = 42
=> 42
irb(main):002:0> Symbol.all_symbols
=> [:"", :"<IFUNC>", :"<CFUNC>", :respond_to?,  ..., :irb_exit_org, :Constant]
```

But now, there is a catch.

```
Symbol.all_symbols.include?(:DoesNotMatter)
```

Before you will run this code, `:DoesNotMatter` doesn't exist in `all_symbols`, but it somehow still exists. Well, actually when you use symbol literal, it's inserted to `Symbol.all_symbols` (unless it's there already). So, the symbol is already here before you even call `.include?`.

EDIT: Gregory Brown suggested following workaround. It works because in Ruby assignment of `Symbol.all_symbols` copies variable for some reason instead of copying the reference to variable.

```
irb(main):001:0> symbols = Symbol.all_symbols; 1
=> 1
irb(main):002:0> symbols.include? :something
=> false
irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: What you've said here is correct, but because Symbol.all_symbols returns a copy of the array rather than a direct reference, if you do something like the following, you can avoid that problem:

    syms = Symbol.all_symbols;
    syms.include?(:DoesNotMatter)

Comment: Turns out what I said is only true in a weird edge case scenario, please see the update to my answer for details.