# Class versus instance methods in the context of global symbols

Tags: ruby, class, oop, global, symbols

I was reading a blog post about [Service Objects](http://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2015/06/02/anatomy-of-service-objects-in-rails/) by [Dave Copeland](https://github.com/davetron5000/) and came across the following line:

> A class in Ruby is a global symbol, which means that class methods are global symbols. Coding to globals is why we don’t use PHP anymore.

I'd like to understand this statement a little more and have some questions.

- How are class methods and instance methods different in the context of symbols?

For example, take the following irb session:

```
irb(main):001:0> Symbol.all_symbols.grep /Foo/
=> []
irb(main):002:0> Symbol.all_symbols.grep /some.*method/
=> []
irb(main):003:0> class Foo
irb(main):004:1> def some_instance_method; end
irb(main):005:1> def self.some_class_method; end
irb(main):006:1> end
=> :some_class_method
irb(main):007:0> Symbol.all_symbols.grep /Foo/
=> [:Foo]
irb(main):008:0> Symbol.all_symbols.grep /some.*method/
=> [:some_instance_method, :some_class_method]
```

- How are `#some_instance_method` and `::some_class_method` different in the context of symbols?
- What am I doing when I check `Symbol.all_symbols` is this the same thing as viewing the "global symbols"?
- Why are both `#some_instance_method` and `::some_class_method` shown? After reading the above quote I would have expected the result of `008` to be:

  irb(main):008:0> Symbol.all_symbols.grep /some.*method/
  => [:some_instance_method]

Answer (score 1):

I think Dave was a little unclear in the way he phrased that, but he explains the impact in the paragraphs following your excerpt:

> A great example of where a service-as-a-global-symbol is problematic is Resque. All Resque methods are available via Resque, which means that any Ruby VM has exactly one resque it can use.
>
> […]
>
> If, on the other hand, Resque was implemented as an object, instead of a global, any code that needed to access a different Resque instance would not have to change—it would just be given a different object.

The difference is in the interface: with Resque, users of the tool “depend on” and interface with specific classes — they're objects, but they're objects relegated to treatment as globals. This is in opposition to interfacing with instance methods on an object, wherein any other object can be subbed in without the dependence on the class of the object.

Thus using class-methods on a global (like an unscoped class definition) is, Dave argues, akin to using global methods, a la PHP.

Comment: So should the above be rewritten as `which means that class methods are _akin to_ global symbols`? I'm still confused what makes a class vs instance method different from the perspective of symbols. It makes sense to me that a class name is in the global _namespace_ and so it can't be reused, but I'm not sure about how that relates to the concept of _symbols_

Comment: @mbigras It doesn't relate to the concept of symbols except that Ruby creates symbols for constants. See this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358727/ruby-koan-constants-become-symbols

Comment: @mbigras: "Symbol" is a perfectly normal English word. Its usage in the article has nothing whatsoever to do with the `Symbol` class in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems with that article:

First off, the use of the word "[symbol](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol)" may be confusing. While the word does, in fact, perfectly describe what the author means, some readers may confuse it with the [`Symbol`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html) datatype in Ruby. So, while not *wrong*, the choice of words is unfortunate in the context of Ruby. "Name" might have been a better choice.

Secondly, he makes an artificial distinction between class and instance methods, but *there is no such thing as a class method* in Ruby. Ruby only has exactly one kind of methods: instance methods. What we call "singleton methods" are actually just regular instance methods of the singleton class, and what we call "class methods" are actually just regular instance methods of the singleton class of an object that happens to be an instance of the [`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html) class.

Thirdly, he makes an artificial distinction between classes and objects, but *classes are objects* in Ruby.

It seems that we he is *really* arguing against, are constants (because they are global names), singletons (which classes usually are), and static state. And while it is certainly true that all of those are bad, he should say so, if that's what he means. (It's also not exactly a new discovery; entire programming languages have been designed based on the avoidance of static state, e.g. [Newspeak](http://NewspeakLanguage.Org/).)

**tl;dr summary**: The article argues against global names, singletons, and static state, but is badly presented and phrased.

Comment: Is the concept of "static state" related to the concept of "stateless"? Because you're saying he's arguing against "static state" but it seems like he's arguing for "stateless" objects; but "static state" seems like it's similar to "stateless". Also, there is no mention of "static state" in the article (I think your point is it should be?) so I'm confused by what you mean by "static state".

Comment: @mbigras What Ruby (and some others) refer to as a “class method” is also known as a static method by other languages. Statelessness isn't related to Jörg's answer as far as I can tell.

Comment: @mbigras: Stateless is more aggressive than just no static state. I mean, if you have no state at all, then you obviously also have no static state, but the OP is not arguing that you should have no state at all, he is only arguing that state should not be static. I guess an even more fitting characterization would be that state should not be *ambient*. The problem with static (or ambient) state is that there is only one of them, there is only one ambient environment, there is only one static name, therefore you cannot have multiple instances of `Resque` (in this example), and that is bad.

Comment: @mbigras: Gilad Bracha, the designer of the mentioned Newspeak programming language (and co-author of the Java Language Specification and Java Virtual Machine Specification) wrote a [short blog post about static state](https://gbracha.blogspot.de/2008/02/cutting-out-static.html). Somewhere down in the comments, he says something interesting, namely that static state is so deeply ingrained in mainstream programming languages (and thus mainstream programmers) that they are simply unable to a) see anything wrong with it, and b) see how you could ever survive without it. But, languages like Self,

Comment: … Newspeak, E, and Scala prove that it is possible, and specifically E and Newspeak show the advantages (in E, getting rid of static state also gets rid of ambient authority, and makes the language capability-safe, in Newspeak, getting rid of static state gives you a powerful module system for free).

Comment: @coreyward: static methods and class methods are different. In particular, static methods are called "static methods" because they are dispatched statically, not dynamically. In Ruby, there is no such thing as a "class method", all methods are dynamically dispatched instance methods. In languages which *do* have class methods, they are not necessarily static. What Ruby *does* have, though, are static *constants*, and *that's* what I believe the author is arguing against, except he doesn't express it in the blog post.

Comment: @JörgWMittag This is kind of missing the forest for the trees. OP had a “do these two things connect” moment that doesn't really require a 350 word essay response.

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1

The `:some_instance_method` and `:some_class_method` symbols merely exist in Ruby's symbol table. They are *not* different in the context of symbols. The `Symbol.all_symbols` result doesn't declare anything about the objects being referenced. If you had:

```
class Aaa
  def kick_it
    logger.debug { "You kicked an Aaa object" }
  end
end
module Bbb
  def self.kick_it
    logger.debug { "You kicked Bbb" }
  end
end
```

You would see only 1 `:kick_it` reported by `Symbol.all_symbols`, even though one of them is a module-level method and the other is an instance method.

### Question 2

The use of the word "symbol" in the article probably made it confusing. A "global symbol" here probably means a name for a member of the set `Object.constants`, or any other constant accessible in the defined constants subtree.

So `Symbol.all_symbols` is not the same as "global symbols" in this case. However all names in the in-memory constants tree would be a subset of `Symbol.all_symbols`, keeping in mind that all scoping information is lost there.

### Question 3

I think the **Question 1** answer above also explains why both symbols are shown in the `Symbol.all_symbols` result.